# Is it possible to prove this conjecture about Collatz sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, collatz-conjecture, decision-trees

I have constructed a tree that looks something like this:
$$
1,2,4,8,16,
\begin{cases}
32,64,\begin{cases}
128, 256, \begin{cases}
512...\\
85...
\end{cases}\\
21, 42, 84...
\end{cases}\\
5, 10, \begin{cases}
20, 40, \begin{cases}
80...\\
13...
\end{cases}\\
3, 6, 12...
\end{cases}
\end{cases}
$$
to visualize all Collatz sequences which arrive at $1$ within $10$ steps. I observed that, as soon as the tree splits into two paths, dividing a "top" number in any brace by the number directly below it always seems to yield a value between 6 and 7.

For example,
$$
\frac{32}{5}=6.4, \frac{20}{3}=7, \frac{512}{85}\approx6.0235
$$
. This also holds when I divide a number on the tree by the number occupying the same position in the brace below the one it occupies, e.g.:
$$
\frac{128}{20}=6.4,\frac{85}{13}\approx6.54
$$
. It's pretty obvious why $32/5=64/10=128/20=256/42=512/80=6.4$. But if we let $S_n$ be the sequence on the tree: $$32, 64, 21, 42, 84...$$
always taking the low path, and we let $T_n$ be the similar sequence:
$$5, 10, 3, 6, 12...$$
, can it be proved that $$6\leq\frac{S_n}{T_n}\leq7$$
for all real $n$ with what is currently known about the Collatz conjecture?

Comment: $\frac{3x+1}{x/2}= \frac{6x+2}x \approx 6$.

Comment: @Somos I did not notice that. I think what you mean to say, however, is that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{6x+2}{x}=6$$.